# html and css trouble with moving aside

Tags: html, css

I am making this demo site and i am having issues with moving the aside right next to the section paragraphs. I am able to move the aside to the right but there seems to be something stopping the aside from moving upwards

May someone look over this and point out any margin errors or any other misteak I've made to prevent this.

```
   <!DOCUTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <title>The J-Prop Shop</title>
    <link href="jpsstyles.css" rel="stylesheets" type="text/css" />

<!-- The J-Prop Shop Sample Page
     Author: Alejandro Muratalla
     Date: 8/20/18 -->



        <style>

        html{

             background-color: #f4f4f4;


        }

        #heading{

            color: #0095f0;
            font-family: cursive;
            font-weight: bold;
            wrap: no-wrap;
        text-size: 60px;
        text-shadow: 2px 2px #000000;

        }


        #heading2{


            font-family: cursive;
            font-weight: bold;
            wrap: no-wrap;
        text-size: 60px;


        }

        h2{
               font-family: cursive;
        }


        p{
          font-family : Lucida Grande , sans-serif; 
        }












        /*
   New Perspectives on HTML
   Tutorial 1
   Tutorial Case

   J-Prop Shop Style Sheet
   Author: David Vinet
   Date:   3/1/2014

   Filename:         jpsstyles.css
   Supporting Files: none

*/

/* Section Styles */

body {
margin: 0px auto;
padding: 0px;
line-height: 1.5em;
width: 98%;
max-width: 980px;
min-width: 250px;
font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif
}

header {
width: 100%;
text-align: center;
}

section {
width: 66%;
float: left;
}

aside {
width: 45%;
margin-top: 2em;
float: up;
border: 3px solid black;
background-color: rgb(255, 177, 255);
-moz-border-radius: 35px;
 border-radius: 35px;
box-shadow:10px 10px 20px #000;
-webkit-box-shadow:10px 10px 20px #000;
-moz-box-shadow: 10px 10px 20px #000;
margin-left: 650px;
margin-top: 10px;
}

footer {
clear: left;
width: 100%;
text-align: center;
margin-top: 5px;
}

footer address {
width: 150%;
clear: left;
font-size: 0.8em;
font-style: normal;
font-variant: small-caps;
border-top: 1px solid black;
background-color: rgb(255, 177, 255);
}

/* Block Styles */
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

header h1 {
margin: 1em 0em;
font-size: 2em;
}

h2 {
margin: 1em 0em;
font-size: 1.5em;
}

header h1 {
margin: 0px;
}

header h2 {
font-size: 1.2em;
font-style: italic;
margin: 0em;
padding-bottom: 0.5em;
border-bottom:1px black solid;
}

article p {
margin: 0.2em 0.9em 0.7em 0em;
}

article ul {
margin: 0.1em 0.8em 0.5em;
}

article ul li {
margin-right: 0.5em;
}

aside h2 {
text-align: center;
}

aside p {
font-size: 0.8em;
margin: 0px 0.7em;
}

aside blockquote {
margin: 1.2em 2em 0em 2em;
}

aside blockquote p {
margin: 0em 0em 2em;
font-size: 0.7em;
}





        </style>
    </head>
<body>
<header>

<hgroup>
<h1><img src="jpslogo.png" alt="The J-Prop Shop" align="center" id=/> </h1>
<h2 align="center" id="heading2">Quality Juggling and Circus Props</h2>
</hgroup>

</header>

<section>

<article>
    <h2>Welcome</h2>
    <p>If you're looking for high-quality, hand crafted
    juggling and curious products, the J-prop Shop is
    the store for you. I've designed and built props
    for the past 35 years, and my products have been
    used by professional entertainers and hobbyists
    through out the world. Our prices are reasonable
    and our quality is excellent.</p>
</article>

<article>
    <h2>Specials This Month</h2>
    <p>
    The following devil sticks are available at a
    special discount for the entire month of may:
    </p>
        <ul>
            <li><strong>Basic Stick ($19.95)</strong>
                The easiest stick to learn with, 
                    but "grippy" enough for the most
                    demanding tricks. Comes in red,
                green, and blue.

            </li>

            <li><strong>Flower Stick ($24.95)</strong>
                A graceful stick with colored tassels.
                Flower sticks float slowly, making them
                ideal for beginners.
            </li>

            <li><strong>Glow Stick ($29.95)</strong>
                The Glow Stick shines brightly at night
                (without the danger of a fire stick)
            </li>
        </ul>
</article>

<article>
    <h2>Quality Tested</h2>
    <p>
    Every item I create is checked and tested before
    being shipped out to assure perfect quality.
    I take pride in every one of my juggling
    props and I want my customers to feel that
    same pride
    </p>
</article>

<aside>
    <h2>Customer Comments</h2>
    <p>
    Here are a few select quotes from our happy 
    family of our customers and assosiates:
    </p>
        <blockquote>
        <p>
        "I'm more than happy to recommend Dave Vinet's products.
        I came apon his work 10 years ago and was immediatly
        impressed by his craftmanshift. He provides well-
        balanced and attractive props which are the perfect
        complement to my performances."
        <cite> &#8212; 
        <br />Thomas Gage, Circus England</cite>
        </p>

        <p>
            "Dave Vinet makes the best juggling equipment on the
        planet. Period."

        &#8212; <cite>Douglas Pederson, Street-Wise Shows</cite>
        </p>


        <p>
        "David has been my main supplier for 20 years. I have
        never had a problem with his equipment and his service
        is impeccable."
        <cite> &#8212; Linda Unger , Linda & Louis</cite>
        </p>

        </blockquote>
</aside>

    <footer>
       <address>
       The J-Prop Shop
       541 West Highland Drive
       Auburn, ME 04210
       (207) 555 - 9001
       </address>
    </footer>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you embed your code into a live example and pinpoint the error you are trying to fix?

Comment: `id=/` ??? Please go once again trough your HTML code and fix all meticulously.

Comment: `<!DOCUTYPE html>` ??? Should be `<!doctype html>` (without `U`)

Comment: I think the problem is you are missing the closing </section> tag.

Comment: When asking a question, you should post formatted code and also explain the problem precisely. It's even better if you remove all unnecessary code, so others can understand your issue. Clear language and highlighting of important parts also go a long way.

Answer (score 1):

You open the `<section>` element for the left content, but you never close it.

Take a look at this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nobv6qwc/5/) with your original code but closing the `section`, just before opening the `aside`.

Answer (score 1):

You have several *syntax errors* in your code. To fix and prevent these you should format your code to make it more readable. This way errors are easier to spot.

If you're new to coding and don't know how to format your code correctly you can use the *"Tidy"* feature of sites like [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) to format your code. Additionally it marks some obvious mistakes in red.

If you are not sure how a HTML tag or CSS property is used [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com) is a free and easy to understand resource.

> I am able to move the aside to the right but there seems to be something stopping the aside from moving upwards

I would *strongly recommend* that you use the [CSS Flex property](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_flex.asp) move the users comments to the right side. Flex is just easier to use in this case and also keeps the content from overflowing into your footer. Additionally you have to remove the margin of the comments, since these block all other content on the left of it.

**CSS flex version:**
[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/pv8brme0/9/) is a working version of your site (but still far from perfect).

**CSS float version:**
I've formatted your code and marked all syntax errors I could find with comments:

```css
html {
  background-color: #f4f4f4;
}

#heading {
  color: #0095f0;
  font-family: cursive;
  font-weight: bold;
  /* MISTAKE */
  /* 'white-space' instead of 'wrap' */
  /* wrap: no-wrap; */
  white-space: no-wrap;
  /* MISTAKE */
  /* 'font-size' instead of 'text-size' */
  /* text-size: 60px; */
  font-size: 18pt;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px #000000;
}

#heading2 {
  font-family: cursive;
  font-weight: bold;
  /* MISTAKE */
  /* 'white-space' instead of 'wrap' */
  /* wrap: no-wrap; */
  white-space: no-wrap;
  /* MISTAKE */
  /* 'font-size' instead of 'text-size' */
  /* text-size: 60px; */
  font-size: 18pt;
}

h2 {
  font-family: cursive;
}

p {
  font-family: Lucida Grande, sans-serif;
}

/*
   New Perspectives on HTML
   Tutorial 1
   Tutorial Case

   J-Prop Shop Style Sheet
   Author: David Vinet
   Date:   3/1/2014

   Filename:         jpsstyles.css
   Supporting Files: none

*/

/* Section Styles */

body {
  margin: 0px auto;
  padding: 0px;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  width: 98%;
  max-width: 980px;
  min-width: 250px;
  font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif
}

header {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

section {
  width: 66%;
  float: left;
}

aside {
  /* MISTAKE */
  /* 66% + 45% = 111% | If you have more than 100% you content overflows! */
  /* width: 45%; */
  width: 30%;
  margin-top: 2em;
  /* MISTAKE */
  /* 'float' does not have a value 'up' */
  /* float: up; */
  float: right;
  border: 3px solid black;
  background-color: rgb(255, 177, 255);
  -moz-border-radius: 35px;
  border-radius: 35px;
  box-shadow: 10px 10px 20px #000;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 10px 10px 20px #000;
  -moz-box-shadow: 10px 10px 20px #000;
  /* MISTAKE */
  /* No content is allowed to enter the margin, so this is not what you want. */
  /* margin-left: 650px; */
  margin-top: 10px;
}

footer {
  clear: left;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 5px;
}

footer address {
  /* MISTAKE */
  /* 150% causes your site to be larger than the screen! */
  /* width: 150%; */
  width: 100%;
  clear: left;
  font-size: 0.8em;
  font-style: normal;
  font-variant: small-caps;
  border-top: 1px solid black;
  background-color: rgb(255, 177, 255);
}


/* Block Styles */

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

header h1 {
  margin: 1em 0em;
  font-size: 2em;
}

h2 {
  margin: 1em 0em;
  font-size: 1.5em;
}

header h1 {
  margin: 0px;
}

header h2 {
  font-size: 1.2em;
  font-style: italic;
  margin: 0em;
  padding-bottom: 0.5em;
  border-bottom: 1px black solid;
}

article p {
  margin: 0.2em 0.9em 0.7em 0em;
}

article ul {
  margin: 0.1em 0.8em 0.5em;
}

article ul li {
  margin-right: 0.5em;
}

aside h2 {
  text-align: center;
}

aside p {
  font-size: 0.8em;
  margin: 0px 0.7em;
}

aside blockquote {
  margin: 1.2em 2em 0em 2em;
}

aside blockquote p {
  margin: 0em 0em 2em;
  font-size: 0.7em;
}
```

```html
<!DOCUTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>The J-Prop Shop</title>
  <link href="jpsstyles.css" rel="stylesheets" type="text/css" />
  <!-- The J-Prop Shop Sample Page
     Author: Alejandro Muratalla
     Date: 8/20/18 -->
</head>
<body>
  <header>
    <hgroup>
      <!-- MISTAKE -->
      <!-- 'id="*put your ID here*"' instead of 'id=' or just remove it -->
      <h1><img src="jpslogo.png" alt="The J-Prop Shop" align="center" /> </h1>
      <h2 align="center" id="heading2">Quality Juggling and Circus Props</h2>
    </hgroup>
  </header>
  <section>
    <article>
      <h2>Welcome</h2>
      <p>If you're looking for high-quality, hand crafted juggling and curious products, the J-prop Shop is the store for you. I've designed and built props for the past 35 years, and my products have been used by professional entertainers and hobbyists
        through out the world. Our prices are reasonable and our quality is excellent.</p>
    </article>
    <article>
      <h2>Specials This Month</h2>
      <p>
        The following devil sticks are available at a special discount for the entire month of may:
      </p>
      <ul>
        <li><strong>Basic Stick ($19.95)</strong> The easiest stick to learn with, but "grippy" enough for the most demanding tricks. Comes in red, green, and blue.
        </li>
        <li><strong>Flower Stick ($24.95)</strong> A graceful stick with colored tassels. Flower sticks float slowly, making them ideal for beginners.
        </li>
        <li><strong>Glow Stick ($29.95)</strong> The Glow Stick shines brightly at night (without the danger of a fire stick)
        </li>
      </ul>
    </article>
    <article>
      <h2>Quality Tested</h2>
      <p>
        Every item I create is checked and tested before being shipped out to assure perfect quality. I take pride in every one of my juggling props and I want my customers to feel that same pride
      </p>
    </article>
    <!-- MISTAKE -->
    <!-- This closing section tag was missing -->
  </section>
  <aside>
    <h2>Customer Comments</h2>
    <p>
      Here are a few select quotes from our happy family of our customers and assosiates:
    </p>
    <blockquote>
      <p>
        "I'm more than happy to recommend Dave Vinet's products. I came apon his work 10 years ago and was immediatly impressed by his craftmanshift. He provides well- balanced and attractive props which are the perfect complement to my performances."
        <cite> &#8212; 
      <br />Thomas Gage, Circus England</cite>
      </p>
      <p>
        "Dave Vinet makes the best juggling equipment on the planet. Period." &#8212; <cite>Douglas Pederson, Street-Wise Shows</cite>
      </p>
      <p>
        "David has been my main supplier for 20 years. I have never had a problem with his equipment and his service is impeccable."
        <cite> &#8212; Linda Unger , Linda & Louis</cite>
      </p>
    </blockquote>
  </aside>
  <footer>
    <address>
     The J-Prop Shop
     541 West Highland Drive
     Auburn, ME 04210
     (207) 555 - 9001
     </address>
  </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS Properties:**

- [CSS float property](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_float.asp)
- [CSS font-size property](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_font_font-size.asp)
- [CSS white-space property](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_white-space.asp)

I hope this helps. *-Minding*

Answer (score 0):

**The problem:**

> I am able to move the aside to the right but there seems to be
>   something stopping the aside from moving upwards

**Short answer:**

You missed to close the `section` tag.

---

here's a runnable snippet that illustrates a working demo for your needs:

```html
<html>
    <head>
    <title>The J-Prop Shop</title>
    <link href="jpsstyles.css" rel="stylesheets" type="text/css" />

<!-- The J-Prop Shop Sample Page
     Author: Alejandro Muratalla
     Date: 8/20/18 -->



        <style>

        html{

             background-color: #f4f4f4;


        }

        #heading{

            color: #0095f0;
            font-family: cursive;
            font-weight: bold;
            white-space: no-wrap;
        font-size: 60px;
        text-shadow: 2px 2px #000000;

        }


        #heading2{


            font-family: cursive;
            font-weight: bold;
            white-space: no-wrap;
        font-size: 60px;


        }

        h2{
               font-family: cursive;
        }


        p{
          font-family : Lucida Grande , sans-serif; 
        }












       


body {
margin: 0px auto;
padding: 0px;
line-height: 1.5em;
width: 98%;
max-width: 980px;
min-width: 250px;
font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif
}

header {
width: 100%;
text-align: center;
}

section {
width: 66%;
float: left;
}

aside {
width: 45%;
margin-top: 2em;
float: up;
border: 3px solid black;
background-color: rgb(255, 177, 255);
-moz-border-radius: 35px;
 border-radius: 35px;
box-shadow:10px 10px 20px #000;
-webkit-box-shadow:10px 10px 20px #000;
-moz-box-shadow: 10px 10px 20px #000;
margin-left: 650px;
margin-top: 10px;
}

footer {
clear: left;
width: 100%;
text-align: center;
margin-top: 5px;
}

footer address {
width: 150%;
clear: left;
font-size: 0.8em;
font-style: normal;
font-variant: small-caps;
border-top: 1px solid black;
background-color: rgb(255, 177, 255);
}

/* Block Styles */
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

header h1 {
margin: 1em 0em;
font-size: 2em;
}

h2 {
margin: 1em 0em;
font-size: 1.5em;
}

header h1 {
margin: 0px;
}

header h2 {
font-size: 1.2em;
font-style: italic;
margin: 0em;
padding-bottom: 0.5em;
border-bottom:1px black solid;
}

article p {
margin: 0.2em 0.9em 0.7em 0em;
}

article ul {
margin: 0.1em 0.8em 0.5em;
}

article ul li {
margin-right: 0.5em;
}

aside h2 {
text-align: center;
}

aside p {
font-size: 0.8em;
margin: 0px 0.7em;
}

aside blockquote {
margin: 1.2em 2em 0em 2em;
}

aside blockquote p {
margin: 0em 0em 2em;
font-size: 0.7em;
}





        </style>
    </head>
<body>
<header>

<hgroup>
<h1><img src="jpslogo.png" alt="The J-Prop Shop" align="center" id="" /></h1>
<h2 align="center" id="heading2">Quality Juggling and Circus Props</h2>
</hgroup>

</header>

<section>

<article>
    <h2>Welcome</h2>
    <p>If you're looking for high-quality, hand crafted
    juggling and curious products, the J-prop Shop is
    the store for you. I've designed and built props
    for the past 35 years, and my products have been
    used by professional entertainers and hobbyists
    through out the world. Our prices are reasonable
    and our quality is excellent.</p>
</article>

<article>
    <h2>Specials This Month</h2>
    <p>
    The following devil sticks are available at a
    special discount for the entire month of may:
    </p>
        <ul>
            <li><strong>Basic Stick ($19.95)</strong>
                The easiest stick to learn with, 
                    but "grippy" enough for the most
                    demanding tricks. Comes in red,
                green, and blue.

            </li>

            <li><strong>Flower Stick ($24.95)</strong>
                A graceful stick with colored tassels.
                Flower sticks float slowly, making them
                ideal for beginners.
            </li>

            <li><strong>Glow Stick ($29.95)</strong>
                The Glow Stick shines brightly at night
                (without the danger of a fire stick)
            </li>
        </ul>
</article>

<article>
    <h2>Quality Tested</h2>
    <p>
    Every item I create is checked and tested before
    being shipped out to assure perfect quality.
    I take pride in every one of my juggling
    props and I want my customers to feel that
    same pride
    </p>
</article>
</section>
<aside>
    <h2>Customer Comments</h2>
    <p>
    Here are a few select quotes from our happy 
    family of our customers and assosiates:
    </p>
        <blockquote>
        <p>
        "I'm more than happy to recommend Dave Vinet's products.
        I came apon his work 10 years ago and was immediatly
        impressed by his craftmanshift. He provides well-
        balanced and attractive props which are the perfect
        complement to my performances."
        <cite> &#8212; 
        <br />Thomas Gage, Circus England</cite>
        </p>

        <p>
            "Dave Vinet makes the best juggling equipment on the
        planet. Period."

        &#8212; <cite>Douglas Pederson, Street-Wise Shows</cite>
        </p>


        <p>
        "David has been my main supplier for 20 years. I have
        never had a problem with his equipment and his service
        is impeccable."
        <cite> &#8212; Linda Unger , Linda & Louis</cite>
        </p>

        </blockquote>
</aside>

    <footer>
       <address>
       The J-Prop Shop
       541 West Highland Drive
       Auburn, ME 04210
       (207) 555 - 9001
       </address>
    </footer>


</body>
</html>
```

**Some notes:**

- Every tag must be closed. Self-closing tags *should* be written as such: `<meta charset="utf-8" />` note the `space` and the `/` in the end of the tag.
- There is no any `CSS` rule named "text-size" that must be `font-size`.
- There is no any `CSS` rule named "wrap" that must be `white-space`.

Hope I pushed you further.